# TSDoc eslint-plugin-tsdoc ignore specific files

Tags: typescript, eslint, typedoc, tsdoc

I have just started using TSDoc combined with TypeDoc and I love it.

I have a little problem, well, annoyance really.  I want the `eslint-plugin-tsdoc` to ignore files that will be used to generate the api documentation, which I will be using [apidocjs.com](https://apidocjs.com) to generate for me.

In `PhpStorm` and `command line` I get warnings for these files, I would like to be able to ignore these.  I have not seen any settings to allow for this.

I have excluded the api tags via `typedoc.json` config file, but this doesn't work for the eslint plugin, which makes sense as they are different.

Is there a setting for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to another question I asked, but similar we have a resolution for this question

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66134916/9431766