# Ignore specific file from specific eslint plugin

Tags: typescript, eslint, tsdoc

I am using `eslint-plugin-tsdoc` which works well, except for files where I don't require the linting, for instance, any api routes which use apidoc instead of tsdoc commenting styles.

This is causing errors when running any linting.  Is there anyway that I can ignore files for the `eslint-plugin-tsdoc`?  I don’t want to ignore the file altogether by eslint because I still need the typescript to be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the override property in .eslintrc file. [Using configuration files to disable for a group of files](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#using-configuration-files-1)

Since `eslint-plugin-tsdoc` only has one rule `tsdoc/syntax`.

You need to add this to your `.eslintrc` file.

```
{
  "rules": {...},
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.test.ts", "/src/demo.ts"],
      "rules": {
        "tsdoc/syntax": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So in the above example it will disable the rule for all files ending with `.test.ts` and the file `/src/demo.ts` and apply this rule for rest of the files.

Comment: that is awesome and just what i needed, thank you